# Why am I getting some of my python functions, when I import my module, but not others?

Tags: python-2.7, python-module, nameerror

I'm writing function libraries in Python 2.7.8, to use in some UAT testing using froglogic Squish. It's for my employer, so I'm not sure how much I can share and still conform to company privacy regulations.

Early in the development, I put some functions in some very small files. There was one file that contained only a single function. I could import the file and use the function with no problem.

I am at a point where I want to consolidate some of those tiny files into a larger file. For some reason that completely eludes me, some of the functions that I copy/pasted into this larger file, are not being found, and a "NameError: global name 'My_variableStringVerify' is not defined" error is displayed, for example. (I just added the "My_", in case there was a name collision with some other function...)

This worked with the EXACT same simple function in a separate 'module'. Other functions in this python file -- appearing both before and after this function in the new, expanded module -- are being found and used without problems. The only module this function needs is re. I am importing that. I deleted all the pyc files in the directory, in case that was not getting updated (I'm pretty sure it was, from the datetime on the pyc file).

I have created and used dozens of functions in a dozen of my 'library modules', all with no issues. What's so special about this trivial, piece of crap function, as a part of a different module? It worked before, and it STILL works -- as long as I do not try to use it from the new library module.

I'm not python guru, but I have been doing this kind of thing for years...

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. What a fool. The answer was in the error, after all: "**global** name xxx is not found". I was trying to use the function directly inside a Squish API call, which is the global scope. Moving the call to my function outside of the Squish API call (using it in the local scope), it worked fine.

The detail that surprised me: I was using "from foo import *", in both cases (before and after adding it to another 'library' module of mine).

When this one function was THE ONLY function in foo, I was able to use it in the global scope successfully.

When it was just one of many functions in foo-extended (names have been changed, to protect the innocent), I could NOT use it in the global scope. I had to reference it in the local scope.

After spending more time reading https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/import.html (yes, it's old), I'm surprised it appeared in the global scope in either case. That page did state that "(The current implementation does not enforce the latter two restrictions, but programs should not abuse this freedom, as future implementations may enforce them or silently change the meaning of the program.)" about scope restrictions with the "from foo import *" statement.

I guess I found an edge case that somehow skirted the restriction in this implementation.

Still... what a maroon! Verifies my statement that I am no python guru.